# Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows option greyed out in Windows Server 2016

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-update

I need office 2019 which is installed on my windows server 2016 to take updates via Windows Update , I seem to have tried every method under the sun to get it work , Deleting registry keys adding registry keys , Setting local group policy to enabled and checking the other updates option , setting it to not configured and then retrying again

Does anyone have any sort of help on this

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the Office Deployment Tool to configure the update source location for Office, as described in the Microsoft documentation: [Update Office 2019 (for IT Pros)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/update). Another possibility is to use enterprise software deployment tools, such as Microsoft Configuration Manager, to manage Office updates. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I did push it through earlier by SCCM but it didnt take the updates not sure what changed but looks like its taking now , Thanks for the help , Tradionally I have noticed this issue is present for me on windows server 2016 not on other versions